# Woocommerce price does not display decimal

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, decimal

I render the woocommerce price for each product in a loop on a "product-card". However, my code does not seem to display the "thousand-decimal" example - 1,200:-.
So what i want happening is that the "," decimal is displayed on the product card, rather then it just typing out "1200:-".

Here's the code

````
        if($loop->have_posts()){
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                global $product;

                $filters = get_the_terms($loop->post, 'product-custom-filter');

                $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
                $in_stock_after_text = get_field('stock_after_text');
            
                if (empty($in_stock_after_text)){
                    $in_stock_after_text = ' + i lager';
                }
                

                $price = $product->get_regular_price();

                $shortdes = $product->get_short_description();
                

                if (!empty($price)){
                    $price .= ' kr exkl. moms';
                }

                $extra_tags = '';

                // Get product attributes
                $attributes = array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'pa_farg',
                        'value' => get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'pa_farg')
                    ),
                    array(
                        'name' => 'pa_tillverkare',
                        'value' => get_the_terms($product->get_id(), 'pa_tillverkare')
                    )
                );
                $extra = '<div style="opacity: 0.5; font-weight: bold;">';
                $attributes_val = '';
                foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
                    $extra .= implode(', ', array_map(function($obj) { return $obj->name; }, $attribute['value'])) . '<br/>';
                    if (!empty($attribute['value'])) {
                        $val = implode(',', array_map(function ($v) use ($attribute) {
                            return $attribute['name'] . '_' . $v->name;
                        }, $attribute['value']));
                        $attributes_val .= $val . ',';
                    }
                }
                $extra .= '</div>';

                echo $twig->render('card.phtml', array(
                    // 'class' => 'product-item--with-shadow text-center',
                    'hasBackground' => true,
                    'class' => 'product-item--unhover-fade',
                    'href' => get_permalink(),
                    'heading' => get_the_title(),
                    'stock' => !empty($stock) ? ($stock . $in_stock_after_text) : '',
                    'shortdes' => $extra, //$shortdes . (isset($_GET['debug']) ? $extra : ''),
                    ///'subheading' => 'Bästsäljare',
                    'price' => $price,
                    'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url($loop->post->ID),
                    'filters' => $filters ? json_encode($filters) : '',
                    'filter_attributes' => $attributes_val,
                    'circular' => count(array_filter($filters, function ($item){
                        // Check if product is circulär
                        return $item->slug == 'begagnat';
                    })) > 0
                ));
```
````

Answer (score 0):

In woocommerce settings, you can choose the number of decimals and the decimal separator. Did you change that or remove it by inadvertance?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Yea, that was the first thing to check ofc. And that was not the issue, however i decided to change the code instead. And here's how i got it to work  ` $price = number_format($product->get_regular_price(), 0, '', '.'); `

It did the trick! :)

Comment: Well done, CodingNoob!